# PHP Static life if the script is called multiple times

Tags: php

We have a class that keeps a static instance of itself.  The class also has a static function that populates private properties properties.  I thought that Unlike C++ those statics were only accessible during the current run of the script(and that is what I have read here on StkO, but without reference to php version).
I am seeing the same self::$instance->cacheSuffix  across runs of the script.  Is it possible that the static instance is being preserved by the php interpreter?  Here is the code.  Thank you for your help.

```
class Events {
  private static $instance = null;
  private $allEvents = null;
  private $calendarMap = null;
  private $calendarEvents = array();
  private $calDate = null;
  private $cacheSuffix = null;
  private $accessToken = null;

  private static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new Events();
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        self::$instance->calDate = date(DATE_RFC3339, strtotime('Today'));
        self::$instance->cacheSuffix = self::$instance->calDate;
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be, no. Separate instances of the script should be separate.

Comment: static !== persistent

Answer (score 0):

Each execution of a PHP script starts with a clean slate.

If you want to persist any variables or objects across requests, you can cache them on the filesystem, db, memory etc. But you have to do that yourself (or implement a library that does provides that functionality)